# Nested Firestore security rules - get()

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Does anyone know if I can create nested ‘get’ rules to access different data in the database? And how?

```
// Assignment's document
match /assignments/{assignmentId} {
    function getAssignmentOwner(){
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/assignments/$(assignmentId)).data.owner;
    }
    function getAgencySupervisors(){
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/agencies/$(getAssignmentOwner())).data.supervisors;
    }

    allow write: if request.auth.uid in getAgencySupervisors();
    allow read: if request.auth != null;
}
```

Currently it returns "not allowed".

Answer (score 0):

Rules are not data filters; you should use rules for just collections, documents or subcollections, you can't use rules to filter results inside a document.

Doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure

Comment: It works if I don't nest them.

This works : get(/databases/$(database)/documents/assignments/$(assignmentId)).data.owner;